# React + Firebase + Python

Tags: javascript, python, django, reactjs, firebase

I have one project that I want to write in React frontend and Firebase as a database. But I need to write some functions with Python, I have some operations with ssh, valve, and FTP. Should I use Django? How to grab data that comes from Python libraries live like from base? What do you recommend?

Btw, I never user Python with Firebase and I have struggles.

Comment: Usually on a project like you're describing you would use Firebase as the backend database and then do everything on the frontend in javascript, so you shouldn't need Python--Django is used for some of the same stuff Firebase is. I'm not sure what your question is?

Comment: Django looks like an overkill for you use case, I would rather go with something lightweight like Flask.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do something in Python which is not possible to be done with firebase just create flask REST API. Then from react app you could make api calls to Firebase/Flask app and do what you want.

But if you want to have everything in one place, you could use https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python this is python sdk for firebase and it could be installed to flask app

Answer (score 0):

First, your question is not so clear down to the specifics. But on a higher level, whatever you want to do should be doable in firebase using Javascript. Firebase comes with **[cloud functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started)**. This allows you to write actual backend code which can be executed either by a trigger or by an http request. So find out if you can find equivalent libraries in npm. Then implement the functionality you want in js. Then plug them into your cloud functions. Voila!!

If you can provide clearer details I might be able to give you more details support.